# Filter column data of table in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter, html-table

I am new to angularjs and learning day by day but somehow I cannot figure out to filter this data to show in table.

In partial, Fail and Success

I want to show that data which has 1 before separator '|'

Ex in Success cell: **1|12311 0|2122** shows result **12311**

**Original table**
[image]

**Result table**
[image]

```
<table class="table table-condensed" border ="1" align="center">
<tr>
<th>Job Id</th>
<th>Job Type</th>
<th>Nb of Urls</th>
<th>Size of Page</th>
<th>Bytes</th>
<th>Site Id</th>
<th>Partial</th>
<th>Fail</th>
<th>Success</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="detailData in detailObject"> 
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.jobId"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.jobType"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.Date"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countUrl"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countBytes"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.sid"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countPartial  | filter: scidStatusFilter"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countFail"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countSuccess"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

// Input JSON

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Getting Data",
  "data": [
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~10:46:27",
      "sid": 1,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~11:2:58",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~11:7:57",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "ondemand",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~12:19:16",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by writting a custom function testing the value for you:

```
<table>
    ...
    <td>{{ successValue(detailData.countSuccess) }}</td>
/<table>
```

And in your scope, define successValue function:

```
$scope.successValue = function(val) {
    if(val.substring(0,2) == '1|') return val.slice(9);
    else return val;
}
```

---

*Note 1: You could probably improve `successValue()` by testing a regex for it, but I'm not a good regex-writter. I just try to explain in this answer what could be the Angular way do to it.*

*Note 2: You are not forced to use `ng-bind` each time you want to display a value from your controller. You can change all:*

```
<td>
    <span ng-bind="detailData.jobId"></span>
</td>
```

To:

```
<td>{{detailData.jobId}}</td>
```

Comment: substring spell mistake and separator '|' is coming so slice shifted to 9
to get result

Comment: @Creator Fixed, my bad. Does the rest of the answer fits your needs?

Comment: Well not perfectly upto certain extant thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this approach and I want my answer like this way.
//html side

```
<td>
  <span ng-bind=" successValue(detailData.countPartial) "></span> 
</td>
```

//js side

```
$scope.successValue = function(val) {
                var aOuterData = [];
                var aInnerData = [];
                var scidData = [];
                aOuterData = val.split(' ');
                angular.forEach(aOuterData,function(val){
                aInnerData = val.split('|');
                if(aInnerData[0]>0){
                scidData.push(aInnerData[1]);
                }
                })
                return scidData.join(',');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this line of code :**

```
if(item.countSuccess.indexOf('1|') != '-1') {
  item.countSuccess = item.countSuccess.substring(item.countSuccess.indexOf('1|')+2, item.countSuccess.indexOf('0|')-1);
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.detailObject = [
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~10:46:27",
      "sid": 1,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~11:2:58",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~11:7:57",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "ondemand",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    },
    {
      "jobId": "2~27-4-2017~12:19:16",
      "sid": 2,
      "jobType": "mode",
      "date": "2017-04-24T18:30:00.000Z",
      "countSuccess": "1|12311 0|2122",
      "countFail": "0|12311 0|2122",
      "countPartial": "1|2122 0|12311",
      "countUrl": 24,
      "countBytes": 246
    }
  ];
  
$scope.detailObject.map(function(item) {
   if(item.countSuccess.indexOf('1|') != '-1') {
     item.countSuccess = item.countSuccess.substring(item.countSuccess.indexOf('1|')+2, item.countSuccess.indexOf('0|')-1);
   }
});

console.log($scope.detailObject);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table table-condensed" border ="1" align="center">
<tr>
<th>Job Id</th>
<th>Job Type</th>
<th>Nb of Urls</th>
<th>Size of Page</th>
<th>Bytes</th>
<th>Site Id</th>
<th>Partial</th>
<th>Fail</th>
<th>Success</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="detailData in detailObject"> 
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.jobId"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.jobType"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.Date"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countUrl"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countBytes"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.sid"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countPartial  | filter: scidStatusFilter"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countFail"></span>
</td>
<td>
<span ng-bind="detailData.countSuccess"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
its ok Rohit my problem is solved I have mentioned my answer above

Answer (score -1):

If your First character will be the dynamic value the you can try the below function,

Template:

```
<table>
    ...
    <td>{{ successValue(detailData.countSuccess) }}</td>
/<table>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.successValue = function(val) {
    return val.split('|')[0];
}
```

> Note: I've taken "Mistalis" Answer to make it dynamic.